# is it possible to define Must Start Times for dependent jobs in AutoSys

Tags: scheduler, autosys

I'm looking for an option in autosys to send an alert if the dependant jobs don't start within 10 min of the avg run time, for example, the last 30 days. The dependant jobs, do not have a fixed starting condition. They might have run at varying times in the last 30 days based on the completion of starting jobs. Would it be possible in autosys, to dynamically set the must start time for the jobs which don't have starting time rather they are dependant on starting conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use something like this in my critical jobs. You can try them too, if you want :

```
must_start_times: "19:01" 
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr,sa,su
start_times: "19:00"
```

Comment: in my case, the child job doesn't have a fixed start time. it runs based on the success status of parent jobs.

Comment: Values of the `must_start_times` and `must_complete_times` have to be fixed. There is no mechanism in Autosys that would estimate average run time of the job and then use it as a variable. Also clarified with few other senior admin for CA, they suggested the same.